# window.addEventListener('message', myFunction(event)) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, firefox, events

I'm trying to understand why the following does not work.

```
var myFunction = function(event) {
    // do something with event
};

window.addEventListener('message', myFunction(event));
```

I get the following error: "ReferenceError: event is not defined".

However, the following works and `event` is able to be used.

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    // do something with event
});
```

How can I use `event` in the first situation? Why is `event` only accessible in the second situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are seeing the error because you are invoking the function immediately. You need to pass a *reference* to the function instead.

In other words, change this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', myFunction(event));
```

to this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', myFunction);
```

When using the `addEventListener()` method, the `event` object will be passed as the first parameter by default when the event is fired.

Comment: Oh! I see, in the first situation I was trying to pass the `event` variable from a different context (that doesn't exist) to my function. Thanks, that makes sense.